# How to create docker image in .NET Core with multiple project?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

All my projects is .NET Core SDK 2.2.

I have 4 projects.

TestData
TestConsole
TestLogic
TestData2.

At startup, I'm setting the Console as the start project and each project has references to each other.

What I wonder is where do I create dockerfile and what should I add to the dockerfile?

Here is my dockerfile current:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Error:

skipping project

TestData.csproj
TestLogic.csproj
TestData2.csproj

was not found.

Comment: Place your docker file to the Solution Items folder (where all your projects exist) and everything should be fine.

Comment: I tried to put it in the root of the solution.

Error:

Copy *.cs proj no source files were specified. COPY FAILED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/aspnetapp/src/TestConsole/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestConsole.dll"]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error.

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf934d8bdb1a8ffda4a1ca52db81827bf3fcddcf8f296dba9b37a38c82fbd60b/merged/app/aspnetapp/src/testconsole/out: no such file or directory

Comment: Try edit this line to:
`COPY --from=build-env /app/aspnetapp/TestConsole/out ./`

Comment: I've only installed docker desktop,  

Error stat '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bec9381dd84b05faba723a10fe7f452b8e1b084eae900fa00e5d90d4d7bb8042/merged/app/aspnetapp/src/TestConsole/out: no such file or directory'

Comment: Remove `src` from `COPY --from=build-env /app/aspnetapp/src/TestConsole/out ./`

Comment: docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name testconsole testconsole, does this look correct? I can't seem to be able to access the localhost

Comment: The dockerfile should be in the solution folder and not in the testconsole project folder ? :)

Comment: Looks ok, but it's better to run interactively mode to see your console outputs:
`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name testconsole testconsole`

Comment: Are you sure that when you run your app locally it runs on 8080 port ? You should map 80 port to the port under which your app running locally.

Comment: do I need to have an account with repo to run it?

Comment: Is it normal to not have the opportunityn to access the database?

Answer (score 3):

To make it efficient you have to copy all the project's `.csproj` files first and then restore to cache the results. Then copy everything else and publish the project. So your Dockerfile will look similar to

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY aspnetapp/aspnetapp.csproj aspnetapp/
COPY TestData/TestData.csproj TestData/
COPY TestLogic/TestLogic.csproj TestLogic/
COPY TestData2/TestData2.csproj TestData2/
RUN dotnet restore ./aspnetapp/aspnetapp.csproj

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish ./aspnetapp -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

You may want to explicitly copy the projects after restore if you have more projects in the solution to reduce the container build time.

In my project I created a tool that creates `COPY` directives for main project dependencies from the command line to simplify the process.